# How to obtain parts of a string

Tags: java

In my program, the program asks the user to add, find and delete nodes in a `TreeMap`.

> add John Do 123-456-789
>
> find John Do
>
> delete John Do
>
> add Michael Jordan 232-323-232

I have a question in regarding how to split the string.  I was wondering how I could use strings add, find, and delete for a switch statement, John Do as a String key, and 123-456-789 as a String value. Is there a way to use `split()`, and obtain the first word, the name, and the value?

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Too basic to be asked here. Try googling yourself

Comment: java tutorial put that in google https://www.google.com/search?q=java+tutorial+strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) and split according to whitespace(s).

```
String str = "add John    Do    123-456-789";
String[] res = str.split("\\s+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(res));
```

Now the result will be:

`[add, John, Do, 123-456-789]`

Now you can obtain the string values from `res` array.

*As stated in the comments, I suggest you to do a little research before posting questions and to give a minimal try. After you do this, if you'll still have problems, you can ask your question here.*

Answer (score 0):

The following code splits the string to an array of strings containing the number tokens separated by hyphens.
`String[] tokens = str.split("-");`

Comment: Please don't just post an answer consisting of a single line of code. Explain what it does and how it solves the problem stated, and please indent code by 4 spaces.